# how to check if the app is installed and open it or redirect to play store

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

I'm building an App with Google Fit, I got all the permissions working, but since Google fit needs to be downloaded from the play store I'd like to know how can I create a button that checks if the App is installed and if it is open it if it is not, redirect to the Play Store